# One routing two layouts?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have one angular app with a routing and two layouts - the first one is a login page and the second one is a customer portal and in my app configuration I have this

`$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'Login.html'
    })
    .when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'Dashboard.html'
    })`

and the first case is executed for both `mydomain.com/` and `mydomain.com/dashboard`

How to execute the second case `'/dashboard'` when the user is redirected to it?

Comment: if you put a link in Login.html pointing to /dashboard and then you go to "/" and click the link, will it load the correct page?

Comment: whatever you have defined in your $routeProvider is # urls for your SPA. If you do a full page call to your server, this configuration will behave same for both server urls

Comment: redirect user to /#/dashboard instead of /dashboard :) This will solve your problem :)